# Android - Socket like http server, sending embed image to browser

Tags: java, android, httpserver

I implemented for my android application a simple HTTP Server which pass html tags with sockets and everything went as expected.

But I'm tried load in the client(browser) an simple embed image (http://localhost:1234/img.jpg\" />) and I don't know how to make the socket load it.
Can anyone help me giving the coordinates to make it?

My simple http server:

```
public class MainClass extends Activity {
  // Called when the activity is first created 
  // It was called from onCreate method surrounded with try catch 
    [...]

ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1234);
while (true) {
  Socket s = ss.accept();
  PrintStream out = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
  String info = null;
  while ((info = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("now got " + info);

    if(info.equals(""))
        break;
  }
  out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
  out.println("MIME_version:1.0");
  out.println("Content_Type:text/html");
  String c = "<html>" +
     "<head></head>" + 
     "<body>" + 
     "<img src=\"http://localhost:1234/img.jpg\" />" + // << Does not load in the browser
     "<h1> hi </h1>" + 
     "</body>" +
     "</html>";

  out.println("Content_Length:" + c.length());
  out.println("");
  out.println(c);
  out.close();
  s.close();
  in.close();
}

[...]

}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the image is not loading is because the file `http://localhost:1234/img.jpg` is not being served by your application. When an `<img />` tag is processed, the browser will go out to the src path and load that file into the page.

I don't know how to implement that offhand (I have not implemented HTTP before). But you would at least have to process the inputed `GET` request, and differentiate between the base webpage and the image request.